# application executer, desktop icons

Tags: html

i would like to run .exe files on my computer from my website,
example:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  
    function RunFile() {  
    WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");  
    WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe", 1, false);  
    }  
</script>  

<input type="button" value="Run Notepad" onclick="RunFile();"/>
```

I googled this and its seems its only possible in IE so i wonder if its possible to do this in all browsers with some sort of application like BF3 or something, a handler of some sort .dll or whatever they use.
I will not abuse this, i can assure you i will only use it for my personal usage and with some friends. I want a html file that can open desktop icons.

Answer (score 1):

The `ActiveXObject` is not part of HTML DOM nor JavaScript/ECMAScript standard. It is only available for Microsoft Internet Explorer (MSIE). MSIE for Mac might also lack support of `ActiveXObject` since ActiveX is Window platform originated.

Comment: MSIE has not been available for Mac OS since 2003. For all meaningful intents and purposes, it does not exist.

Comment: but is it possible to create some kind of handler that the person have to download first, an exe that can talk to the browser and that "program, addon" in turn says to the computer to start exe.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to launch local applications from web pages. As you've no doubt surmised, it's far too easy to abuse.

Comment: but is it possible to create some kind of handler that the person have to download first, an exe that can talk to the browser and that "program, addon" in turn says to the computer to start exe.

Comment: It is technically possible, but it is a terrible idea and you should not do it.

Comment: to there its not possible to activate a desktop icon from a website?

Comment: in a good way and secure way?* it doesn't matter if there is popup warnings on the site and you need to accept and stuff

Comment: No, there is no way to do this securely. Popup warning are typically a sign that something insecure is going on, and this case is no exception.

Comment: thanks anyway! your answers have been very helpful with destroying my hopes :)